# Get element by name

Tags: c#

I am trying to loop trough something 3 times and change the .text property of 3 element that have the names "label1", "label2" and "label3". I'm trying to add the 1,2,3 to the label but I can't get it to work.

this is what I'm trying to do: 
the y is either 1,2 or 3

```
("label" + y).Text
```

Comment: You are trying to access property of string, it is invalid. Could you expain which type of component means it asp. Net or winform etc.,you need to find that component using name then access text proprty of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this,so I make a simple code of it.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("label" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly - you can do this using reflection:

```
var temp = (double)typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("label" + y).GetValue(myClassInstance);
```

if you change the type of `MyClass` to the class that holds your variable, `myClassInstance` to an instance of your class and the cast from double to your field type (which I'm guessing is some sort of WPF / Winforms control) you can get the variable by name.

It's important to note that your program will slow down if this is used often.